# Apache httpd: mod_proxy_hcheck URL based HTTP basic authentication

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, httpd, mod-proxy, healthcheck

I am trying to use mode_proxy_hcheck to do health checks and failover for an application that requires HTTP Basic authentication.

```
<proxy balancer://serverpool>
  BalancerMember http://username:password@hostname1 hcmethod=GET hcexpr=expression hcuri=/rest_or_url hcinterval=1
  BalancerMember http://username:password@hostname1 hcmethod=GET hcexpr=expression hcuri=/rest_or_url hcinterval=1
</proxy>
```

This is not working. This is the log message I get

```
[Tue Sep 06 22:02:57.434388 2022] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 2044:tid 2140] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(704): AH03254: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

If you have successfully managed to do something similar, your advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Move infrastructure to the cloud. In AWS terminology, setup an Application Load Balancer that sits in front of EC2 instances which includes health checks for high availability architecture. Job done.

Use whatever cloud provider you choose.

Comment: This is not an option currently